# Loop Not performing as expected when using detachChild() and addChild()

Tags: java, android, andengine

*This question refers to andengine GL-ES1.*

I am having trouble making a wallpaper activity that refreshes when your return to it, or when the user performs actions in the game.

My game has two activities. In one, you can edit and arrange the background elements in a room. In the other you play the game, and it uses the same background with the elements you arranged in the first activity.

There is also a live wallpaper in which your room is the background and characters move around in front of it.

I am making updtaes in onResume() in the wallpaper.

first I detach all the backgroudn sprites i used before. 
Then I attach new sprites in the updated positions.

What happens is: some of the sprites don't show up.

Here is the method: Can you see anything I'm doing wrong?

```
    private void loadBackgroundDecorations() {
    //Add new decorations
    Log.d(TAG, "loadBackgoundDecorations");
    mEngine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {          
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Remove Old Decorations
            Log.d(TAG, "loadBackgoundDecorations: decorationList.size() =" + decorationList.size());
            while(decorationList.size() > 0){
                Sprite d = decorationList.remove(0);
                scene.detachChild(d);
                Log.d(TAG, "loadBackgoundDecorations: detachChild");
            }
            decorationList.clear();
            //Add new decorations
            ArrayList<Integer> decorations = app.getBackgroundManager().getDecorations();
            Log.d(TAG, "loadBackgoundDecorations: decorations.size()" +decorations.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < decorations.size(); i+=3) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Decoration Values: texture-"+decorations.get(i)+", x-"+decorations.get(1+i)+", y-"+decorations.get(2+i));                   
                Sprite draggable = new Sprite(decorations.get(1+i),decorations.get(2+i),mGameTextureRegionLibrary.get(decorations.get(i)));
                draggable.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
                scene.attachChild(draggable,0);                 
                decorationList.add(draggable);
                Log.d(TAG, "loadBackgoundDecorations: attachChild"+ i);
            }
        }
    });


}

@Override protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();               
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mTexture, this, app.getAquariumBackground(), 0, 0);
    addBubbles();
    loadBackgroundDecorations();
    addCharacters()
}
```

============ UPDATE =================
As some people have suggested below, I tried adding all the scene setup functions into the runnable. This has no effect. What has worked for me is to set the "wrong" decorations visible property to "false". But I am worried that this will eventually cause a memory leak as more and more duplicates of the sprites are hidden on the wallpaper. 
The problem only exists when I call "detachChild". For some reason that seems to prevent "attachChild" from firing correcly. Anybody have ideas for what could be causing this?

Can anyone else create an activity that adds and removes sprites in the onResume function?

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain that the error has to do with your onResume method. The order you have your methods in is

```
addBubbles();
loadBackgroundDecorations();
addCharacters()
```

but your loadBackgroundDecorations uses a runnable so there is no guarantee that the method will run in between.

**My Explanation:**

From what I understand both addCharacter and addBubbles will be running on the UIthread whereas the loadBackgroundDecorations method will run on the update thread. The two threads will go through the methods at different times and that is where you are seeing some inconsistencies.

**To Fix:**

Put addBubbles and addCharacters in the same runnable in the order that you want and it should work as expected.

Comment: I think that is not it. The function does not need to run inbetween the other two methods (which is why they written in that way). The runOnUI thread is there to make the detachChild() thread safe. But neither the bubbles nor the characters are large enough to obscure the decorations. The problem is that when the loop executes, one item is not added. However, if I leave out the detachChild() calls it adds all of them - unfortunately it also leaves all of the old ones too. Any other ideas?

Comment: Tried the suggestion above, moved all functions into the runnable. No change. Its something else. Still searching...

Comment: Try removing the runnable completely. I am not 100% sure if on resume is run on the update thread or not, but if it is then I am pretty sure you will get errors due to trying to run a runnable on the update thread while already on the update thread. This may sound counter intuitive, but it is the only other thing I can think of.